# Kettle: how to set a person-student relationship?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, etl, kettle

i want to make an ETL operation over MySQL. 

I have a table 'person':

```
Person
{ PersonId : Integer, (PK, auto_increment)
  FName : String, 
  LName : String }
```

and a table 'Student':

```
Student
{ PersonId : Integer, (FK)
  RegistrationNumber : Integer }
```

How should i procede to make an ETL trasformation to a structure as above?

EDIT 2012-12-12
[image: Strutcure]

I want to trasform from the Student structure to a Person-Student one.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? I can't really tell what you want to do from the way this question has been asked. To assist you we probably need to know, at the least, the source of the data and the destination.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to join the Person and Student table. To do that, just add a Table Input step, select your database connection, and put in an SQL that does the join. Joined rows will flow out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a fact table along with these two tables.

> Person
>   { PersonId : Integer, (PK, auto_increment)
>     FName : String, 
>     LName : String }
>
> Student
>   { PersonId : Integer, (FK)
>     RegistrationNumber : Integer }

have a table as say Fa_Individual with structure like

> Fa_Individual { PersonId : Integer, (from Person table)
>     FName : String, 
>     LName : String, 
>     RegistrationNumber : Integer (from Student table) }

You can have a "Left Outer Join" in your SQL, to fetch data at aggregated level. This would be a good idea.